# Error with iterator in for loop in java script(With onload function in filereader)

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, js-xlsx

The code :

```
    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
    var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
    var k=1
    var desired_cell = worksheet['A'+k].w;
```

The above code runs fine
But :

```
       for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        var obj = {};
        var cell = (worksheet[('A'+i)]).w;
        obj.PickUpDate = cell;
        obj.PickUpTimeSlot = cell;
        obj.PickUpAddress = cell;
        obj.DeliveryAddress = cell;
        obj.BoxType = cell;
        array.push(obj);
    }
```

this code gives an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'w' of undefined
at FileReader.reader.onload
```

The line:

```
var cell = (worksheet[('A'+i)]).w;
```

is fine as I can print the 'cell' to console.
Both the snippet are in `FileReader.reader.onload` function.
I am using xlsx package https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

What is wrong with that code?

Comment: Do you have 50 cells defined ?
(worksheet[('A'+i)]) is undefined at some point, you should investigate at which index !

Comment: No. Those were undefined. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the SheetJS/js-xlsx docs :

> Built-in export utilities (such as the CSV exporter) will use the w text if it is available. To change a value, be sure to delete cell.w (or set it to undefined) before attempting to export. The utilities will regenerate the w text from the number format (cell.z) and the raw value if possible.

You can't be sure that `(worksheet[('A'+i)]).w` is defined.

I don't know what your worksheet data is but maybe that could do the job :

`var cell = (typeof (worksheet[('A'+i)]).w !== 'undefined') ? worksheet[('A'+i)]).w : worksheet[('A'+i)]).v;`

Hope it helps.